# Different XML values for SmartPhone vs Tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to have different XML values for `imageview height's` and `imageview width's` for my app. The problem is that i Need different values for the height's and width's for the *smartphone version* and the *tablet version*. Would there a way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use different dimension files according to your requirement in resource folder like multiple drawables https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension

Comment: @Pavan thanks, worked perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Resource Qualifiers in Android [Check Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Define the image width & height in dimens file

**values/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_width">100dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**values-sw600dp/dimens.xml**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="image_width">150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**In the activity/fragment xml**

```
<ImageView
     android:width="@dimen/image_width"
     android:height="@dimen/image_height" />
```